# Why does $form_state->get('XXX') return an empty value after the form has been submitted?

Tags: 8, forms

In the [QueueExampleForm.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/queue_example/src/Forms/QueueExampleForm.php?h=8.x-1.x)) file, which is part of the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) project, why does `$form_state->get('insert_counter')` always return an empty value after the form has been submitted and an item was inserted into the queue?

Comment: Cross-posted on https://www.drupal.org/project/examples/issues/2978404

Comment: @Clive – Would this make this question off-topic then as well?

Comment: @leymannx Pings only work if someone was on the comment/post.  We tends to avoid crossposting across SE, but tolerate (to an extent) crossposts to D.O.  What we don't want are bug reports here.

Comment: @mpdonadio, the reason why I first come here was because in my opinion Drupal official examples code should be something well tested before putting that in the official repository. Because lot of people take it naturally as a Bible!!! But now, I think really that it is a bug and non my misunderstanding.

Comment: @ostry.sn No worries.  I think this is a good question here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug. So in order to keep the incrementing textfield.
we can remove the setting/getting of the useless arbitrary property "insert_counter" and exploit the call of existing instruction :

```
$items = $this->retrieveQueue($queue_name);
```

In resume, we can just replace :

```
'#default_value' => $this->t('item @counter', ['@counter' => $form_state->get('insert_counter')]),
by
'#default_value' => $this->t('item @counter', ['@counter' => count($items) + 1]),
```

And remove the `$form_state->setRebuild();` inside the addqueue submit handler

Answer (score -1):

Lets try with

```
$form_State->getValue('insert_counter');
```

or

```
$form_State->get('insert_counter')->getValue();
```

Comment: In fact, "insert_counter" is not a field form, but an arbitral property set dynamically

Answer (score -1):

I think try below code

```
$textfield_1 = $form_state->getValue('insert_counter');  //'#tree' => TRUE
 $values = $form_state->getValues(); // '#tree' => TRUE
```

Comment: In fact, "insert_counter" is not a field form, but an arbitral property set dynamically